# Delete image thumbnail from gallery when it got hidden

Tags: java, android

this question has been asked before(not specifically like this) but there hasn't been an All Exclusive answer to it yet. so we are trying to find the best solution here. i'm developing an app and in my app i hide a directory named `myPic` by moving it's files to a directory called `.myPic`. when i hide my pictures it's thumbnails are still in gallery. i find 3 solution to this:

### first solution:

using **ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED** broad cast like this:

```java
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

the problem with this code is that it takes hug resources and most importantly it is **blocked since android 4.4**. so using this method is not rational for adding 10 pictures to gallery. so it is not an All exclusive method. also using `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` doesn't work on android 4.4 either

### second solution:

using `MediaScannerConnection`. so i created a `for` loop and pass the old address of every file that i hide. this is my `MediaScannerConnection` function:

```java
private void scanFile(File file) {
    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });
}
```

the thing about `MediaScannerConnection` is that it only effect if the file exist. so lets say i have a picture called `1.jpg` in `myPic` directory. using this class i can add `1.jpg` to my gallery immediately but when i move `1.jpg` to `.myPic` directory and i scan the old path of `1.jpg` nothing happen. logcat says that this file doen't exsit. so `MediaScannerConnection` only add files to gallery. what if i pass the new path of `1.jpg` to `MediaScannerConnection`? well it adds `1.jpg` from `.myPic` directory to gallery and that is exactly **not** what i want. so again **not an All Exclusive** method

### third solution:

using `getContentResolver()`. so for deleting thumbnails this method may be the ultimate solution. so i write the blow code. in every loop i retrieve the path of image and pass it to `getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(path),null,null)`. here is the code:

```java
File myPic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myPic");
File myPicHide = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.myPic");
if (!(myPicHide.exists()) & !(myPicHide.isDirectory())) {
    myPicHide.mkdirs();
};
if (myPic.isDirectory()) {
    String[] childeren = myPic.list();
    if (childeren.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < childeren.length; i++) {
            String fileName = childeren[i];
            File from = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myPic"+fileName);
            File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.myPic"+fileName);
            from.renameTo(to);
            try {
                String path = from.toString();

                getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(path),null,null);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Rename", "Error happened");
            }
        }
    }
} else { 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "myPic directory not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but it's not working either and thumbnails of my files are still showed in galley. so am i using `getContentResolver()` in wrong way?? this might be the all Exclusive method for the situation where deleted files thumbnails show up in gallery. i have my files path and i need to only delete it from media store content provider.

**update:**
so turns out that using `Uri.parse(path)` in the third solution is wrong. image Uri is started with `content://` and it can be retrieved by `MediaScannerConnection`. so i created a `Uri` called `imageInGalleryUri` and assign `null` value to it. using my `scanFile` function i changed it's value from time to time and pass it's value to `getContentResolver()`. here is the code:

```java
    boolean whereIsMediaState = true;
    Uri imageInGalleryUri = null;
    
    File myPic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myPic");
    File myPicHide = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.myPic");
    if (!(myPicHide.exists()) & !(myPicHide.isDirectory())) {
        myPicHide.mkdirs();
    };
    if (myPic.isDirectory()) {
        String[] childeren = myPic.list();
        if (childeren.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < childeren.length; i++) {
                String fileName = childeren[i];
                File from = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myPic"+fileName);
                scanFile(from);
                File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.myPic"+fileName);
                from.renameTo(to);
                if (to.isFile()){
                try {
                    getContentResolver().delete(imageInGalleryUri,null,null);}
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Rename", "Error happened");
                }
            }
        }
    } else { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "myPic directory not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        
        private void scanFile(File file) {
            // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
            // immediately available to the user.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            imageInGalleryUri = uri;
            }
            });
        }
```

i tried the code but it only detect the first image and delete it from the gallery but does not effect the other images. i can't figure out why. any idea?

thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

. before folder just make it invisible. But there is way to say don't use this folder at all to gallery.
Please try to put empty file called ".nomedia" file into your folder.

Comment: first of all it's `.nomedia` and it does not work on every android version. we are looking for an all exclusive answer